# bigquery authenticating with service account from text\string and not file path

Tags: google-bigquery, google-authentication, google-auth-library-nodejs

I am using
[this nodejs bigquery client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs)

I have the service account json in string\text, I want to avoid to write it to temporary file due to security reasons. 
Is there an option to do `new BigQuery()` and provide the service account as string and not as filepath? 
Couldn't find this option anythere, in all the examples need to provide the filepath or export the *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use the values in your service account as string for authentication. You can use [BigQueryOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/global.html#BigQueryOptions) and pass a credentials object. Credentials object will need `client_email` and `private_key` which can be found in your service account json.

Using the [sample code you linked in your question](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs), `BigQueryOptions` can be implemented in this manner.

```
const creds = {
        client_email: 'your_service_account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery(credentials=creds);
```

The whole code will be:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const creds = {
        client_email: 'your_service_account@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery(credentials=creds);

async function query() {
  // Queries the U.S. given names dataset for the state of Texas.

  const query = `SELECT name
    FROM \`bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013\`
    WHERE state = 'TX'
    LIMIT 100`;

  // For all options, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query
  const options = {
    query: query,
    // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location: 'US',
  };

  // Run the query as a job
  const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

  // Wait for the query to finish
  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

  // Print the results
  console.log('Rows:');
  rows.forEach(row => console.log(row));
}
query()
```

Snippet of the output:

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got 'Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.' are you sure you dont have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable exported?

Comment: i think i made it work by adding the projectId. Thanks!